# function field of open curve and compactificaton

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, function-fields

Let $U$ be a smooth curve over some field $k$ and $C$ the only smooth projective curve containing $U$ as a dense open subset.

Can someone help me understading why the function fields of $U$ and $C$ are equal?

Comment: The function field of a variety $C$ is the same as that of any of its open nonempty subsets $U$.

Comment: Yes, this is the statement I'm trying to understand

Answer (score 0):

This is Hartshorne exercise II.3.6. The point is that the function field can be identified with the local ring of the generic point.